# Closing steps in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say I have the following plot:

```
x = array([ 40,  60,  80, 100, 120, 138, 160, 200, 240])
y = array([ 6,  5, 11,  6,  6,  0,  2,  1,  3])

plt.figure()
plt.step(x, y, where='mid')
plt.show()
```

How can I make the same plot so that the blue line starts and ends from the axis **y=0** ?

[image]

Comment: Does `x = array([0,  40,  60,  80, 100, 120, 138, 160, 200, 240]), y = array([0, 6,  5, 11,  6,  6,  0,  2,  1,  3])` not solve the problem?

Comment: Also, why doesn't the plot match the data? For example, it jumps up at x=150 in the plot, but you don't have a data point for x=150.

Comment: @Bill - Answering your second question. notice that I am using `where='mid'` which asks it to target the middle point, i.e. not 150, but 160.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add null values at the beginning and the end of your list `y`, and update the axis `x`:

```
y_bottom = [0] + y + [0]
x_bottom = [x[0]] + x + [x[-1]]
```

and then plot the same way:

```
plt.figure()
plt.step(x_bottom, y_bottom, where='mid')
plt.show()
```

[image: Figure with lines starting at bottom]